# How convert AVFrame to Compose Image?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

Here is the approximate [code](https://gist.github.com/habibg1232191/c3bcafb22ffcc17132c1a590f97e6b5c), but it doesn't display the image.
This code works. But nothing is displayed.

Take an example code from [here](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/main/experimental/ffmpeg/SkVideoDecoder.cpp)

The task is to make a player on ffmpeg.

Comment: I haven't worked with it, so I can't give you working code, but you create a bitmap and read its value at the end, but you don't write any data to it. Instead you write to `pFrameRgb` and don't read it.

Comment: and what should be done with it?  This is my first time writing something like this, and I don't really know how to do it right.

Comment: In the example they're passing `bm.pixmap().writable_addr()`, but I wasn't being able to find how to get it from kotlin. I suggest you asking it in [kotlin slack](https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up), **#compose-desktop** channel, I think there're better chances of getting an answer there.